# Run complex update query on remote server using OPENROWSET

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Could you please help me with below task. I need to run below query on remote server

```
UPDATE prod
    SET prod.count = ( SELECT SUM(Inv) FROM cost WHERE pID = prod.ID)
    WHERE (( SELECT COUNT(id) FROM Cost WHERE pID = prod.ID ) > 0)
```

I have tried to use OPENROWSET but do not have enough experience working with it and all online examples with OPENROWSET that I saw use only one table. Can you please give me an idea how to modify this query to use OPENROWSET or ideas of any other solutions?

Comment: Show what query you have tried using OPENROWSET. And by remote server do you mean that the cost table is on a linked server?

Comment: both prod and cost tables are on remote server

Comment: I tried the following ' UPDATE prod SET prod.Count = ( SELECT SUM(Inv) FROM Cost WHERE pID = prod.ID )
                FROM OPENROWSET(''SQLNCLI'', ''Server=<<INSTANCENAME>>;Database=<<DBNAME>>;Uid=<<USERNAME>>;Pwd=<<PASSWORD>>'',
                ''select * from prod'') AS d WHERE( ( SELECT COUNT(id) FROM Cost WHERE pID = prod.ID ) > 0)';

Answer (score 0):

You can use direct `linked server` or `OPENQUERY (linked_server_name ,'your query')`.

Best way to to this is to create procedure on target instance and use only easy exec on linked server to run procedure.

```
exec LinkedServer.TargetDB.TargerSc.NewProcedure
```

`Openrowset` is used to "open row set" - primary to access remote data, to modify remote data is `openquery`.

Comment: Hi, My TargetDB, TargetSc are dynamic and gotten from some master DB, is it possible to use this format in such case?

Comment: Yes, but servers have to be connected with linked server (with proxy account).

Comment: is this possible to use OPENQUERY (linked_server_name ,'your query') with such complex update query?

Comment: Sure, your query can be complex. But you should prefer stored procedure.

Comment: I need to update several servers, does it mean all of them should have this SP created? And can I call SP with dynamic names something like exec ["LinkedServer"].["TargetDB"].["TargerSc"].NewProcedure?

Comment: If you would like to run this more times so yes, you should. If it will be ad-hoc qry use qry directly with OPENQUERY.

Comment: as for openquery, do you mean it should be like UPDATE OPENQUERY(TLLINKSERVER, "select prod.count from prod WHERE ( SELECT COUNT(id) FROM Cost WHERE pID = prod.ID ) > 0)")
SET prod.count = ( SELECT SUM(Inv) FROM cost WHERE pID = prod.ID), but will it get SELECT SUM(Inv) FROM cost WHERE pID = prod.ID from remote server as well

Comment: Easiest way: UPDATE prod
    SET LinkedServer1Name.DB1name.prod.count = ( SELECT SUM(Inv) FROM LinkedServer1Name.DB1name..cost WHERE pID = prod.ID)
    WHERE (( SELECT COUNT(id) FROM LinkedServer1Name.DB1name..Cost WHERE pID = prod.ID ) > 0) but prefer stored procedure.

Comment: how can I write LinkedServer1Name.DB1name.prod.count  if server name/ DB name is a variable? Does it supports ["LinkedServer1Name"].["DB1name"] etc format?